# JxBrowser - showing popup on MAC hangs

Tags: macos, javafx-8, jxbrowser

Showing popup hangs on MAC using JavaFX. I use jxbrowser 6.7.1 and OSX 10.10.5.

Here is the code:

```
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.BrowserCore;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.Environment;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.javafx.BrowserView;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFX extends Application {

@Override
public void init() throws Exception {
    // On Mac OS X Chromium engine must be initialized in non-UI thread.
    if (Environment.isMac()) {
        BrowserCore.initialize();
    }
}

@Override
public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
    Browser browser = new Browser();
    browser.setPopupHandler(new com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.javafx.DefaultPopupHandler());

    BrowserView view = new BrowserView(browser);

    Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(view), 700, 500);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    browser.loadURL("http://www.popuptest.com");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

The same code works great on WIN OS. Someone help me please.

Comment: I found that popup works fine if I use lightweight browser type. Heavyweight browser type hangs.

Comment: This is a known issue in JxBrowser on macOS. Please the lightweight rendering mode as a workaround. In one of the next versions we will fix this issue.